# Magento 2: Shipping Methods not reload automatically

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I have problem regarding Shipping Methods update. Shipping Methods value does not update automatically. I have to reload the page every time, so can anybody have a solution for this. I added a custom shipping method so can it be possible this thing is happening because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just follow this link on**
[github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13810)

[2nd link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8240)

[3rd link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13430)

**in this you will get your answer**

Comment: if it help just up vote the answer. or comment down

Comment: Ok,i will check and reply you for this and thank for your help.

Comment: ok late me know which issue you got, and there solution so we can help others too :)

Comment: In 3rd link i found a solution

Comment: great , in that the 1st issue was mine :)

Answer (score 0):

I got another module in which custom shipping is updated on checkout page
https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-custom-shipping